# which way will be better foreach loop insertion or batch query insertion in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have 3000 row ,i want to insert this row in database ,which would be the best way to insert record in database 
way 1 : by loop through the row

```
       for(int i=0i<=3000;i++)
{
insert into database
}
```

or by creating a sqlquery by concenating string like
string sqlquery

```
 for(int i=0i<=3000;i++)
{
sql+="insert into database";
sql+="#";
}
```

and run this sql query in batch.

Comment: The best option would be to put all insert statements in strinbuilder and do one transaction only...

Comment: You would have to define what you mean by "better" in order for this question to be answerable.  Faster?  Less error-prone?  Do you need to do any processing per-row before inserting?

Answer (score 0):

You should make only one SP call and prepare the data using XML. And finally parse the XML on the sp side. This will be much faster and optimal.